# Manipulate a dom element on a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I'm new to angular and wanted to know how can i manipulate a dom element, select tag specifically, when a user clicks a button.

This is the code i'm using:

parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-recipe',
    templateUrl: './add-recipe.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-recipe.component.css']
})
export class AddRecipeComponent implements OnInit {

    units = [
        { id: 1, name: "test" },
        { id: 2, name: "test1" },
        { id: 3, name: "test2" },
        { id: 4, name: "test3" }
    ];

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    addIngredient(object) {
         // doing stuff
    }
}
```

parent view:

```
 <input #ingredientName type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
 <input #ingredientQty type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="qty">
 <app-select-units [units]="units"></app-select-units>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="addIngredient({ name: ingredientName.value, quantity: ingredientQty.value, unit: chosenUnit }); ingredientName.value=''; ingredientQty.value=''; ingredientUnit.value=''">add</button>
```

child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
      selector: 'app-select-units',
      templateUrl: './select-units.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./select-units.component.css']
 })
 export class SelectUnitsComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() units: string[];

      @Input() selectedUnit: string;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
  }
```

child view:

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="chosenUnit" #ingredientUnit class="form-control" name="selectUnit">
      <option value="" [attr.selected]="!selectedUnit ? true : null" disabled>select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let unit of units" value="{{ unit.id }}" [attr.selected]="selectedUnit == unit.id ? true : null">{{ unit.name }}
      </option>
  </select>
```

when the user clicks the button on the parent component, it calls it's "addIngredient" method, and clearing the two inputs.

i also try to clear the select to the first option (i know it's not possible this way).

Is there any way to bind the select to the parent component and clear it once the button click?

Comment: Have you looked into EventEmitters and ngOnChanges ?

Comment: Why don't you just change this.selectedUnit in parent component? like this. selectedUnit = this.units[0];  in  addIngredient function. And for now i don't see you set selectedUnit input param

Comment: you should try another solution, like for example ReactiveForms using reactiveformArray to add dynamically the fields that you want to display

Comment: If you use `[(ngModel)]="selectedUnit"`, you don't need to set the `selected` property on the options. You can set `[value]="null"` for the first option, and `[value]="unit.id"` for the other options, and rely on the binding with `selectedUnit`. To reset the selection: `this.selectedUnit = null`.